# Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: c#, android, navigation-drawer

I have an application menu I had created that has been working just fine for over 10 months.  I recently created a release and uploaded it to Google for release to my alpha testers.  Prior to that I attempted to create a splash screen ([Android Splash Screen doesn't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518338/android-splash-screen-doesnt-display?noredirect=1#comment107110006_60518338) which failed miserably, so I commented out the lines in the manifest in order to create the release and get it out to my testers which is still pending on Google console.  I then went back to debug mode and everything went to hell in a hand basket.  What a mess.  I researched and corrected all the errors I was getting except this one, I simply cannot make the navigation view work.

This is the layout that contains the navigation view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
  <ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.75" />
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is nav_header_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Main Menu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is side_nav_bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:centerColor="#FFD700"
        android:endColor="#FFD700"
        android:startColor="#FFD700" 
        android:type="linear" />
  <!--FFD700 gold 42586E original -->
</shape>
```

I had removed all code related to the splash screen attempt.

I have no idea why this drawer menu is no longer working.  I've looked all over for answers and have found nothing.  Why is this all of sudden not working when it had been working right along?  What am I missing?

Comment: The "side_nav_bar" file needs to be start like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >.    Can you confirm this?

Comment: @Logo Sorry, copy and paste error.  Corrected the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  Seems like the line:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

got removed from the manifest:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Organize My League" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:icon="@mipmap/launchicons">
</application>
```

I added it back in:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Organize My League" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:icon="@mipmap/launchicons" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

Now the NavigationView inflates properly.  Maddening little things like this happen all the time.  No idea at what point the theme line disappeared, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

One probable solution could be that you're missing the `android:layout` attribute which is a reference to the View that will be inflated next to a call of inflate().
Also, you can check the version of your `appcompat` library and design support library match.

Comment: Missing it where?  The libraries versions match.

Comment: that's missing in the ViewStub.

Comment: That's handled programmatically in `Drawer.cs` with the line `                stub.LayoutResource = Resource.Layout.User;
                View inflated = stub.Inflate();`

Comment: Oh, okay. You can check this answer too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472963/android-kitkat-android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-sup

Comment: Not the issue here, I target sdk 28 (pie) with minimum sdk 26 which is Marshmallow(sp?) I believe.  No "extra" drawable folder is/was created.